# How can I make a div's height and width the same using responsive design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive design and am having a difficult time trying to make some div's height and width both the same. At first I made the div's width a percentage and changed its height to auto, however this only caused the div's to not display. In this example I have to  have a fixed height in pixels to allow the div's to show. I am not able to acheive this problem with the use of simple images, but instead I must use background images inside of divs that need to be responsive with a equal with and height that are responsive. When I re-size the browser, I need the divs to change size as squares not rectangles. How can I achieve this?

An example of the following on jsFiddle, can be found using the shortened url at, http://bit.ly/ZLiBm2

Comment: create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net with your fluid  css for width as framework...can adjust height with script in window resize handler

Answer (score 1):

Try the method in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZYTST/

Use the `padding-bottom` as the percentage of height you want for your element and then set `height` as `0` and `width` as same value of `padding-bottom`.

Comment: I tried this technique, but the elements still disappear. If you have another div inside of this one that has position of relative and a z-index, would this effect the main div to not display when setting the height? If so, why?

Comment: Here is a working example of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/jdmagic21/ENnpE/1/